# Ordering DIVs based on class name using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="red">2</div>
    <div class="red">3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div class="red">6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

I wast to run some Jquery that will sort the divs inside the div container by ordering the divs *first* that have class="red", and then those that don't, so the final structure should be:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="red">2</div>
    <div class="red">3</div>
    <div class="red">6</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Help? Thanks.

Comment: Bonus points if the re-ordering is done with with some sort of animation, to make it obvious to the user that the div order has changed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the JavaScript/jQuery you've written so far?

Comment: Just curious. In the first place, why have you arranged them that way?

Comment: Bonus Points? same is for you, if you try soimething by yourself., before posting it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(function(){
   var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(sortMe);
   $('#container').append(elem);
 });

 function sortMe(a, b) {
        return a.className < b.className;
  }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zyEwF/)

With Some `fadeIn/fadeout` animation

```
var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(sortByClass);

 function sortByClass(a, b) {
    return a.className < b.className;
 }

 var allElem = elem.get();
  (function append() {

    var $this = $(allElem.shift());

     $('#container').append(
                $this.fadeOut('slow'))
                         .find($this)
                             .fadeIn('slow', function () {
                                      if (allElem.length > 0) 
                                          window.setTimeout(append);
                            });
      })();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JKfZS/)

Comment: Hey this works great thanks! Is it possible to make it work with the second class name? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sorting is not required here. As the elements are already in the order you need, you can just call `prependTo()` on them, like this:

```js
$('.red').prependTo('#container');
```

```css
.red { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="red">2</div>
    <div class="red">3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div class="red">6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best answer. Works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Add 2 buttons to your html

```
<button class="sort">SORT</button>
<button class="unsort">UNSORT</button>
```

Attach click handlers...

```
$('.sort').click(function(){
 var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(doSort);
 $('#container').append(elem);
}

$('.unsort').click(function(){
 var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(doUnsort);
 $('#container').append(elem);
}
```

Sorting functions

```
function doSort(a, b) {
 return a.className < b.className;
}

function doUnsort(a, b) {
   var a = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var b = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
   return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zyEwF/11/)

Answer (score 2):

Following PSL's answer, I had to add `? 1 : -1` to the sortMe function like so:

```
$(function(){
   var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(sortMe);
   $('#container').append(elem);
 });

 function sortMe(a, b) {
        return a.className < b.className ? -1 : 1; // This is the added code
  }
```

Thanks to Alex and Rejith who answered my similar question [How to _prevent_ divs from appearing in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619783/how-to-prevent-divs-from-appearing-in-random-order)