# How to _prevent_ divs from appearing in random order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, so I'm learning front-end dev with javascript/jquery/bootstrap through FreeCodeCamp. This is not a core part of the project, but I don't understand it and it's distracting me too much. In this code pen here:
http://codepen.io/JDenman6/pen/zqeGwp/ --
I have an array of Twitch.tv usernames that I check through an API and build divs to display them based on the JSON object comes back from the API call.

The weird thing is that every time I refresh the page, I get the divs in a different (apparently random) order. I'm guessing that the API calls are going out asynchronously and the divs are appearing in the order that the API calls finish.

When I Googled for other people having problems with divs in random order I found many solutions for *causing* random display order, but nothing on *preventing* it. So then I went looking for a solution to sorting divs and found this post, [Ordering DIVs based on class name using Javascript/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017148/ordering-divs-based-on-class-name-using-javascript-jquery), which led me to this bit of code:

```
 $(function(){
   var elem = $('#twitcherList').find('div').sort(sortMe);
   $('#twitcherList').append(elem);
 });

 function sortMe(a, b) {
        return a.className < b.className;
  }
```

Only I haven't been able to get it to work. I forked off my original codepen to do some poking around here: http://codepen.io/JDenman6/pen/MeYOJP.

The list of divs in the twitcherList in the html tab is from inspecting the twitcherList after rendering the original code. I thought it might be easier to sort them if they're hard coded, rather than coming in from the API call. I also added a little test div and inserted some code into the sort function to 1) check that it was running and 2) double check that a.classname and b.classname were returning what I thought they were, which they are.

I feel like I'm missing something massive, fundamental, and possibly quite obvious. Any thoughts?

Comment: Each elements have different classes, how do you want to sort them? based on the first one in the list?

Comment: `sortMe` must return 1, 0, -1 values depending on comparison result. `return a.className < b.className ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `-1`, `0` or `1` based on the condition for proper sorting.

```
function sortMe(a, b) {
     return a.className.localeCompare(b.className);
}
```

For better browser support use,

```
function sortMe(a, b) {
     return a.className < b.className ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Alex and Rejith! I assumed a true/false value would work in the sort function. it makes sense that it needs to be +/-1. Thanks again!