# Add elements to top of list if element has content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unsorted list return results

```
<div style="priority-content</div>
     <div style="top">has content</div>
     <div style="date">has content</div>
     <div style="date">has content</div>
     <div style="top">has content</div>
</div>
```

how can I put .top elements to top of list only if .top has content to get result below? If no content in .top should not be pushed to top.

```
 <div style="all-content>
 <div style="priority-content</div>
     <div style="top">has content</div>
     <div style="top">has content</div>
     <div style="date">has content</div>
     <div style="date">has content</div>
</div>
<div style="main-content"</div>
     <div style="top"></div>
     <div style="date"></div>
     <div style="date"></div>
     <div style="top"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `style="top"`? Surely you mean `class="top"`, right?

Comment: It seems you haven't tried anything. At least post a markup that is valid.

Comment: of course class... tired

Comment: If you meant to say 'class' instead of 'style' please [edit] your question to correct the oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selectors.
Use both to determine if a div is empty or some content.
Then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017148/ordering-divs-based-on-class-name-using-javascript-jquery) for how to order by class.

Comment: That seems to be a lot of work for a "tired" designer.

Comment: "Read this link, and this link and then go to this last link..." This isn't much of an answer, given it's effectively links-only. And implies the question is a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not denying any of that David, it's a tired answer to a tired question.