# Sort divs with chosen class names

Tags: jquery, class, sorting

Sorting divs by alphabetical order with class names is possible (like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017148/ordering-divs-based-on-class-name-using-javascript-jquery)). But is it possible to sort divs in a chosen order.. Example :

I'd like to sort divs in a color order. The divs' classes are `red` `orange` `yellow` and `green`. And I would like for the red to appear first, then orange, etc...

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zyEwF/526/) is what I did so far, thanks to the post linked above but I couldn't get further. Any help? Thank you!

```js
var elem = $('.ic').find('div').sort(sortMe);

function sortMe(a, b) {
  return a.className < b.className;
}
$('.ic').append(elem);
```

```css
.ic {
  width: 850px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 144px 0px 40px 116px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ic:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.icon img {
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ic">



  <div class="icon green">

    <img src="http://img1.foroffice.ru/upload/iblock/381/oracal-641-63.jpg" />

  </div>




  <div class="icon orange">

    <img src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-t-52446-200-hfaogtbebggwzikykcugzhqhvafgpkfs.jpeg" />

  </div>




  <div class="icon yellow">

    <img src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFCC00.png" />

  </div>





  <div class="icon orange">

    <img src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-t-52446-200-hfaogtbebggwzikykcugzhqhvafgpkfs.jpeg" />

  </div>






  <div class="icon yellow">

    <img src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFCC00.png" />

  </div>





  <div class="icon yellow">

    <img src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFCC00.png" />

  </div>






  <div class="icon green">

    <img src="http://img1.foroffice.ru/upload/iblock/381/oracal-641-63.jpg" />

  </div>





  <div class="icon red">

    <img src="http://www.symbols.com/gi.php?type=1&id=2201" />

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assigning numeric values to your colors:

```
var sortValues = {
  red: 0,
  orange: 1,
  yellow: 2,
  green: 3
};
```

And giving yourself a regex that will isolate just the color class from the other clases on the elements:

```
var rexValues = /(red|orange|yellow|green)/;
```

Then, you use the regex to get the color class, look up that value on the values array, and sort based on it with the standard `a - b` numeric pattern:

```
function sortMe(a, b) {
  var aclass = a.className.match(rexValues);
  var avalue = aclass ? sortValues[aclass[0]] : 99;
  var bclass = b.className.match(rexValues);
  var bvalue = bclass ? sortValues[bclass[0]] : 99;
  return avalue - bvalue;
}
```

`match` will return `null` if there's no match, or an array containing the color class as the first element if there is. So we use a conditional operator (`? :`) to check whether there was a match and look up the sort value if there is, otherwise we use 99 (obviously pick whatever number you want there).

The standard numeric sorting `return avalue - bvalue` works like this: If `avalue` is greater than `bvalue`, `avalue - bvalue` is positive; `sort` expects a positive number from the callback to mean the first element should be *after* the second. If `avalue` is less than `bvalue`, `avalue - bvalue` is negative, and `sort` expects a negative number from the callback to mean the first element should be *before* the second. If they're the same, of course `avalue - bvalue` is `0`, which is what `sort` expects when the elements are "equal" (can be in either order).

Live Example:

```js
var sortValues = {
  red: 0,
  orange: 1,
  yellow: 2,
  green: 3
};
var rexValues = /(red|orange|yellow|green)/;
var elem = $('.ic').find('div').sort(sortMe);

function sortMe(a, b) {
  var aclass = a.className.match(rexValues);
  var avalue = aclass ? sortValues[aclass[0]] : 99;
  var bclass = b.className.match(rexValues);
  var bvalue = bclass ? sortValues[bclass[0]] : 99;
  return avalue - bvalue;
}
$('.ic').append(elem);
```

```css
.ic {
  width: 850px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 144px 0px 40px 116px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ic:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.icon img {
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ic">



  <div class="icon green">

    <img src="http://img1.foroffice.ru/upload/iblock/381/oracal-641-63.jpg" />

  </div>




  <div class="icon orange">

    <img src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-t-52446-200-hfaogtbebggwzikykcugzhqhvafgpkfs.jpeg" />

  </div>




  <div class="icon yellow">

    <img src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFCC00.png" />

  </div>





  <div class="icon orange">

    <img src="https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-t-52446-200-hfaogtbebggwzikykcugzhqhvafgpkfs.jpeg" />

  </div>






  <div class="icon yellow">

    <img src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFCC00.png" />

  </div>





  <div class="icon yellow">

    <img src="http://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFCC00.png" />

  </div>






  <div class="icon green">

    <img src="http://img1.foroffice.ru/upload/iblock/381/oracal-641-63.jpg" />

  </div>





  <div class="icon red">

    <img src="http://www.symbols.com/gi.php?type=1&id=2201" />

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, this works great! Quick question if you don't mind: I'm not sure what the x is for here? And also I would never have found the last line of sortMe, do you think you could very quickly explain it? Thank you!!

Comment: @MaëlleJumel: The `x` thing wasn't very efficient, so I've removed it above, and explained what I've done instead along with the callback return value.