# Jquery find() class with regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have div elements that have an icon inside, and I want to use the find() method to return which of the 4 types of icons is inside. Is there a way to use find() with a regular expression to return the class?

EDIT: I've updated the divs to show how the `<i>` is "buried" within the div and not a direct child

```html
<div id="a" class="tile">
   <span>
       <span>
           <i class="led-red"></i>
           Led Red
       </span>
   </span>
</div>

<div id="b" class="tile">
   <span>
       <span>
           <i class="led-green"></i>
           Led Green
       </span>
   </span>
</div>

<div id="c" class="tile">
   <span>
       <span>
           <i class="led-yellow"></i>
           Led Yellow
       </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

```js
var rexValues = /(led-green|led-yellow|led-red|led-null)/;

//this would work for element "a" if element "a" had the class attached,
//but because the class is buried inside I need to use find()
var aclass = a.className.match(rexValues);

//I'm looking to do something more like
var aclass = $(a).find(rexValues);
```

This is part of a sort function where I am sorting the divs based on their icon. The solution I'm basing off of is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46026203/9537489

Comment: What do you mean by `the class is buried inside`?

Comment: Just a quick thought don't know if it'll work but can't you do something like  
var aclass = $(a).find('i').className.match(rexValues)

Comment: @Mina as in the class "led-red" is not a class of div "a", it's a class of an icon inside div "a". 

I say buried just to emphasize there's no easy <i> id I can reference it's just an icon class somewhere inside the div along with other html

Comment: @TD3V I replaced 'className' with 'attr("class")' and you might be on to something, good suggestion!

Comment: Alternative approach might be to set a `data-led-status` on the outer div. Then you are independent of the inner HTML structure. it should be faster too since you don't have to query for subelements... Even tough this won't be really noticeable.

Comment: `<i class='led led-red'`> (etc) then you can just do `$("a .led")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex when not needed

I am using the sort order from your linked answer

`container` can be `document.body` if you do not have a static container near the tiles, but then the tiles will be moved if you have other stuff in the container. Let me know if you need to replace in place

I use the `[...nodeList]` spread syntax because `sort` is not a native method of a nodeList. NOTE: the spread has to be on the querySelectorAll statement or the tiles will not retain their sort order

```js
const container = document.body; // document.getElementById("container");
const sortOrder = { red: 0, orange: 1, yellow: 2,  green: 3 };
const tiles = [...container.querySelectorAll(".tile")]; // needed for the .sort
const getClassStartingWith = (elem, cls) => [...elem.classList].filter(clss => clss.startsWith(cls))[0];
const prefix = "led-";
tiles.sort((a, b) => {
  const aClass = getClassStartingWith(a.querySelector("i"), prefix).replace(prefix, "");;
  const bClass = getClassStartingWith(b.querySelector("i"), prefix).replace(prefix, "");
  console.log(aClass,sortOrder[aClass],bClass, sortOrder[bClass],sortOrder[aClass] - sortOrder[bClass])
  return sortOrder[aClass] - sortOrder[bClass]
});
tiles.forEach(tile => container.appendChild(tile))
```

```html
<div id="c" class="tile">
  <span>
    <span>
      <i class="led-yellow"></i>
      Led Yellow
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="b" class="tile">
  <span>
    <span>
      <i class="led-green"></i>
      Led Green
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="a" class="tile">
  <span>
    <span>
      <i class="led-red"></i>
      Led Red
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to process this, I've never heard of the spread operator and I'm still a bit unfamiliar with the arrow function. Very cool solution, thank you! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with my setup - I believe this could be because my <i> is not a direct child of the "tile" <div>. I'll edit my question to match it a bit better

Comment: I've updated to show the hierarchy, and yes all tiles are inside of a container div as you've done

Comment: @Seltonu Sorry, it was document.body when no other container - fixed with your HTML

Comment: This ended up working nicely, thank you so much! I really appreciate it, gonna have to make use of the spread operator more often it's so cool

Answer (score 1):

the `find` method in jQuery doesn't support this. There is an extension that you could use to [add this functionality](http://web.archive.org/web/20210414101639/https://j11y.io/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)

Are those classes with the prefix limited or unique? You could use the selector *startsWith* (`[<attr>^=<value>]`, i.e. `[class^=led-]`). [Here's the CSS selector reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) if you don't want to add the jQuery based functionality

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what does limited or unique prefix mean here? There can be many "tile" divs on the page, each with a certain led color. But each div would only have one led color at a time - is this what you mean by unique?

Comment: "limited prefex" / "unique prefix" means they *all* start with `led-` as in your example.

Comment: You *probably* don't want to use `[class^=...]` in the general case as it will rely on the order of classes.  If you only have one in the specific case, then ok, but `class='red blue'` would act the same as `class='blue red'` but not be found with `[class^=blue]`

Comment: @freedomn-m That's a good point regarding the css selector. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a codepen, https://codepen.io/matt6frey/pen/wvmZYRL, showing 2 alternatives with CSS selectors. Although the CSS method of doing this only would relate to styling, and not some dynamic functionality.